# Communicate with Java program from Python

Tags: python, java, subprocess, pipe

My Python progam is "check.py"

```
import os.path,subprocess
from subprocess import STDOUT,PIPE

def compile_java(java_file):
    subprocess.check_call(['javac', java_file])

def execute_java(java_file):
    java_class,ext = os.path.splitext(java_file)
    cmd = ['java', java_class]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=PIPE,stdin-PIPE,stderr=STDOUT)
    stdout,stderr = proc.communicate("viraj")
    print stdout
```

My Java program is "Test.java"

```
import java.util.*;
class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Tested Successfully");
        Scanner t=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the string");
        String str=t.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Hello "+str);
       }
}
```

Here, in `check.py`, I am passing a parameter `viraj` as `proc.communicate("viraj")` and hence my output is

> Tested Successfully
>   Enter the string
>   Hello viraj

However, I don't want to pass the parameter. Instead I want the output as

> Tested Successfully
>   Enter the String

and then after I enter the string as `viraj`, it should get printed as `Hello viraj`
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

To interact with the java program, simply call `communicate()` with no arguments.

```
def execute_java(java_file):
    java_class,ext = os.path.splitext(java_file)
    cmd = ['java', java_class]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
    proc.communicate()
```

Comment: I have also tried this solution.. But the output is "Tested SUccessfully Enter the string" and then "java.util.noSuchElementException: No line found" is coming..

Comment: Oops, remove the `stdin = PIPE` from the call to `subprocess.Popen`.